# Fatal error: Class not found simple autoloading with php and composer

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I have a simple set up structure like this:

```
/lib/
    / Car/Honda.php
    / MyClass.php
/vendor/composer/
/vendor/autoload.php
/composer.json
/index.php
```

Composer .json is like so

```
{
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
        "": "./lib/"
      }
    }
}
```

My index.php is like so

```
<?php

require_once('./vendor/autoload.php');
$new = new \Car\Honda(); // this one not found
//  $new = new MyClass() // this one works
```

I didnt add a namespace in the composer.json, as I am just experimenting. I did add

```
"App\\": "lib/"
```

The whole thing does not work. Am I missing something really simple here???

Note: Also tried composer dump and composer dump-autoload. And still not working what gives...

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Car\Honda' not found in
>   /var/www/html/index.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/html/index.php on line 4

Comment: Are you sure autoload.php exists inside 'vendor' folder?

Comment: @gopi , yes there is an /composer/ and /autoload.php in the vendor folder. So I dont get it. It works with MyClass.php living inside the /lib/ but not with /Car/Honda.php..

Comment: can you also include the exact error statement ?

Comment: @Gopi error added.

Comment: Use ` "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "lib"
      ],
    "psr-4": {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Most example online, sets the namespace psr-4 {"namespace//" : "library_folder"} like so.

For this one, I did not specify the namespace in the composer.json file.

In your class, always specify namespace of the folder.

```
/lib/Car/Toyota/Camry.php

namespace Car/Toyota; // this is the one missing.
class Camry {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "lib/"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
    }
},
```

Comment: Ugh still not working. I copied this and still getting same error. Then with "psr-4": { "":"lib/ "} still didnt work. By the way Im running a docker container if it makes any difference.